# Views table columns not sortable

Tags: views, 8

Standard drupal field types like Strings, Numbers, Dates and Taxonomies can be defined as **Sortable** in Views with `Format: Table`.

But more complex fields like Hierachical Taxonomies and Paragraphs or paragraphs don't have a checkbox to make them Sortable.

Is there any way to make them sortable using Views interface or do I have to make a custom plugin  Tablesort with EntityQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Categories or Paragraphs are just references when you create a node view.
Thus when you use them in the fields (as output) they are not sortable but you can add a relationship to them and then their individual fields (like name, id etc) become sortable

Here is an example with tags (on article content type)

Added term relationship **Taxonomy terms on node** and then **tag id** and **tag name** are **sortable** (among others)

[image]

[image]

**ΝΟΤΕ:** you will most certainly end up with duplicate results in the view. For this you can use aggregation, "Group results together" with group column "entity id".

Comment: Thanks, that works out great for Taxonomy terms and also for Paragraphs. But I can't figure out how to make a reference to the second value of a multiple values field. I can't find a delta anywhere, any hint for that?